# Should a responsive site include <mobile:mobile/> in its sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, responsive-webdesign

Should a website built with [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) include [Google's `<mobile:mobile/>` xml tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34648?hl=en) in its sitemap.xml? In other words, will marking each of my urls as "mobile" in the sitemap for a responsive site indicate to Google that these urls are *not* desktop friendly (when, in fact they are)? What is the best practice in terms of sitemaps for responsive sites? One sitemap with `<mobile:mobile/>` in each `<url>`? Two identical sitemaps, one containing `<mobile:mobile/>`, and the other not? One sitemap without `<mobile:mobile/>`?

Comment: Responsive design is not necessarily a mobile site though a mobile site can be responsive. Responsive designs are intended to, generally speaking, avoid having a separate mobile site. This feature is for a separate mobile site. If you do not have a separate mobile site, then you you do not have to create a mobile sitemap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google seems a little fuzzy about it, but I would say **no**, you shouldn't mark responsive pages as mobile.

The page you linked to states:

> A Mobile Sitemap can contain only URLs that serve mobile web content. Any URLs that serve only non-mobile web content will be ignored by the Google crawling mechanisms.

Taking this *exactly* as written, it could mean that all URLs in your mobile sitemap must be formatted for mobiles (which they are), but technically they could be simultaneously formatted for desktop too.

But I think the implication is that the URLs should be *only* for mobiles and not responsive.

The fact is, Google detects responsive sites perfectly well, so if those URLs are in a standard XML sitemap it knows they work fine on both mobile and desktop.